# byebug isn't displaying the output as I type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

I've experienced an odd interface glitch.

```
[44, 53] in /document.rb
    44:     code
    45:   code
    46: 
    47:   def code
    48:     byebug
 => 49:     code
    50:       code
    51:     code
    52:   end
    53: 
(byebug) {here is where you type}
```

When I type, the characters are not displayed at all.  I can type `p "yo"` or whatever I want, and when I hit `enter` it runs the code.  Essentially I can use byebug in a pinch, but it's really frustrating when I can't see what I'm typing.

I've used byebug in the past with this same laptop, and this issue is fairly recent.

I was assisting a friend, and when he used byebug the same issue happened.  I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: Are you using Spring with Rails? If so disable the spring gem, kill all spring processes, and then retry.

Comment: @Casper, that totally fixed it.  I didn't even disable the spring gem, I just killed the server, ran `bin/spring stop` and started the server again.

It's working now, disabling the spring gem might be a more permanent fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR: Add this line in `config/puma.rb`:

```rb
# Specifies the `worker_timeout` threshold that Puma will use to wait before
# terminating a worker in development environments.
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"
```

##### Reproducing & Why this is happening

In development mode, set a `debugger` in a controller action and send a request to this action (e.x. `index`). After 60 seconds Puma, Rails' default server, will terminate the worker. Unfortunately, the next time a `debugger` is triggered you will be unable to see any text you type in the terminal.

This is a [known bug and is fixed in Rails 7+](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b43ede6b9d4dd88300dbe541a61108d86ff11a32). The above line was added to change Puma's worker timeout to a more appropriate level (1 hour) when in development mode.

#### Other Causes

1. As u/casper pointed out in a comment above, Spring can also cause similar behaviour. Stop your server and run `bin/spring stop` and this may resolve your issue.
2. If you're experience only *some* text appear when you type, this may be a result of parallelized tests. For example, if you type, `"Hello World"` but only `"Hol"` appears (i.e. some letters), you can disable parallelized tests following u/sajad-rastegar's advice above. Simply comment this line in `test/test_helper.rb`: `parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the tests run in parallel. Commenting this line in `test_helper` should fix the problem:

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)
```